# First return time in an interval for N particles rotating on the circle at constant random speeds

Tags: pr.probability, mp.mathematical-physics, ds.dynamical-systems

Here is my problem: draw N velocities $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$ in $[-\pi,\pi]^N$ from some measure (Haar measure of uniform independent for simplicity) and make $N$ particles rotate around the circle with these velocities: $\theta_i=v_i \,t$ corresponds to the position of the $i^{th}$ particle at time $t$. Define the arc interval $\theta \in [-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ around the point (1,0) (from which all particles start at $t=0$). My question is the following: do we have an estimate of the first return time for all particles in this interval, that is to say the first time when all N particles come back into $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$?
For a given set of velocities, I know that this is a hard problem depending on the continuated fractions and Diophantine properties of the velocities (at least for $N=1$). But since I am only interested in the mean of such quantity (relatively to the measure used to draw the velocities), I was hoping that selecting randomly the velocities would only keep the generic set of velocities and hopefully give a simple answer. Numerics suggest that the first return time looks like an exponential distribution that would be consistent with the fact that for a generic set of velocities the system is rapidly mixing. But is there any existing results and theorems supporting such observation?

Comment: You are simply looking at a translation flow on the $N$-torus, so volume consideration will give you an easy (uniform) upper bound. I guess that other properties, dependent on the chosen measure, should be reachable with this point of view.

Comment: Clearly, we need to impose a condition that (at least some) particles actually leave $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ at some point (otherwise, all sufficiently small times work). Do you want to require this for at least one particle or for all particles?